# noncopyable static const member class in template class

Tags: c++, templates, static-members, composition, noncopyable

I have a non-copyable (inherited from `boost::noncopyable`) class that I use as a custom namespace. Also, I have another class, that uses previous one, as shown here:

```
#include <boost/utility.hpp>
#include <cmath>

template< typename F >
struct custom_namespace
    : boost::noncopyable
{

    F sqrt_of_half(F const & x) const
    {
        using std::sqrt;
        return sqrt(x / F(2.0L));
    }

    // ... maybe others are not so dummy const/constexpr methods

};

template< typename F >
class custom_namespace_user
{

    static
    ::custom_namespace< F > const custom_namespace_;

public :

    F poisson() const
    {
        return custom_namespace_.sqrt_of_half(M_PI);
    }

    static
    F square_diagonal(F const & a)
    {
        return a * custom_namespace_.sqrt_of_half(1.0L);
    }

};

template< typename F >
::custom_namespace< F > const custom_namespace_user< F >::custom_namespace_();
```

this code leads to the next error (even without instantiation):

**error: no 'const custom_namespace custom_namespace_user::custom_namespace_()' member function declared in class 'custom_namespace_user'**

The next way is not legitimate:

```
template< typename F >
::custom_namespace< F > const custom_namespace_user< F >::custom_namespace_ = ::custom_namespace< F >();
```

What should I do to declare this two classes (first as noncopyable static const member class of second)? Is this feaseble?

Comment: Why don't you just use only static member functions? Is there really a need for an instance?

Comment: @ahenderson yes I do, but `custom_namespace` has additional `typedefs` and other features that depends of `F`.

Comment: @Pubby This extraneous matter. The answer to this is beyond the scope of this discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is being parsed as a function declaration, not an object definition.

The solution is to get rid of the parenthesis:

```
template< typename F > ::custom_namespace< F > const custom_namespace_user< F >::custom_namespace_;
```